# SQL Объединение 3-х таблиц в запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть 3 таблицы

`Контакты: id, name, type (клиент, автор)`

`История книги: id, UsrClientId, UsrAuthorId, UsrCurrentBookId, UsrGivingDate, UsrPlanedReturnDate`

`Книги: id, name`

Клиент может брать книги.

У книги есть автор, который так же как и клиент находится в таблице контактов.

Как мне получить таблицу такого формата: имя клиента, название книги, автор, дата выдачи, дата возврата?

Пробовал выполнять такой запрос:

```
Select Contact.Name,
UsrHistoryDetail.UsrAuthorId, 
UsrHistoryDetail.UsrCurrentBookId,
UsrHistoryDetail.UsrGivingDate,
UsrHistoryDetail.UsrPlanedReturnDate
From
Contact join UsrHistoryDetail On Contact.Id = UsrHistoryDetail.UsrClientId
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как через `UsrAuthorId` и `UsrCurrentBookId` получить имя автора и название книги в эту таблицу.

Comment: Воспользоваться оператором JOIN. Для более подробного ответа покажите что вы уже пробовали и в чем конкретно возникли сложности.

Comment: Select Contact.Name, UsrHistoryDetail.UsrAuthorId, UsrHistoryDetail.UsrCurrentBookId, UsrHistoryDetail.UsrGivingDate, UsrHistoryDetail.UsrPlanedReturnDate  
From Contact join UsrHistoryDetail On Contact.Id = UsrHistoryDetail.UsrClientId
Пока смог сделать так, не знаю как правильно получить через Id имя автора и название книги

Comment: Не здесь. Дополните ответ. Там можно нормально отформатировать код и всем читающим будет понятней вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не привели название таблицы с книгами. Подставьте сами. Для решения я дважды заджоинил таблицу контактов. Один раз по id клиента, другой по id автора. Проверьте, всё ли ок.

```
select 
    c_client.Name,
    b.name,
    c_author.Name,
    h.UsrGivingDate,
    h.UsrPlanedReturnDate
from UsrHistoryDetail h
    join Contact c_client on c_client.Id = h.UsrClientId
    join Contact c_author on c_author.Id = h.UsrAuthorId
    join Books b on b.id = h.UsrCurrentBookId -- Не написали название таблицы с книгами
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает как надо!